# Switching limit and infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Dominated convergence theorem for an infinite product states that:

$$\lim_{n \to ∞} \prod_{k=1}^{∞}(a_{kn}+1)=\prod_{k=1}^{∞}\lim_{n \to ∞} (a_{kn}+1)$$

If 
There exists a convergent sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_{k}$$ such that (for all k)$$b_{k}{\ge}|a_{nk}|$$
To prove this based on hint :
I have said that if :  $$\lim_{n \to ∞} \prod_{k=1}^{∞}(a_{kn}+1)=\prod_{k=1}^{∞}\lim_{n \to ∞} (a_{kn}+1)$$  then  $$\lim_{n \to ∞} \sum_{k=1}^{∞}\ln(a_{kn}+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{∞}\lim_{n \to ∞}\ln (a_{kn}+1)$$ This is true since log is continuous and log of a product is the sum of logs. Now we may use the familiar dominated convergence for infinite sum on this and say that this is true if there exists a **convergent** sum with terms $c_{k}$ such that(for all k)$$c_{k}{\ge}|\ln(a_{nk}+1)|$$ But I do not understand why it is enough to find a **convergent** series with terms $$b_{k}{\ge}|a_{nk}|$$
I think  we can somehow construct a **convergent** series with terms $ c_{k}{\ge}|\ln(a_{k}+1)|$ using a **convergent** series with terms $b_{k} {\ge} |a_{k}|$ and so than the above will be enough but I don’t know how exactly to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac {\ln (1+t)} t \to 1$ as $ t \to 0$. Hence there exists a consatnat $c$ such that $|ln (1+t)| \leq c|t|$ for $|t|\ \leq \frac1  2$. Note that for $k$ sufficiently large we have $b_k <\frac 1  2$ and this makes $|a_{nk} |<\frac 1  2$ for all $n$ and $k$ sufficiently large. I hope the rest of the argument is clear.

Comment: $\sum b_k$ is convergent.  This implies that $b_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.  @VivaanDaga

Comment: It is not true that $\frac {\ln (1+t)} t$ is bounded  wherever it is defined. As $t \to -1$ the inequality fails. Anyway we are only interested in $t$v close to $0$. @VivaanDaga

Comment: I am applylng my inequality for $t=a_{nk}$ and I know that $|t| <\frac 1 2 $ for $k$ large. Why do you make an issue of something that is not needed in my proof? If you find  a logical error in my proof please let me know.

Comment: To prove your result it is enough to start the product from $k=$ some $k_0$ . Becasue there is no problem in interchanging a finite product and a limit.

Comment: Ok I understand . Can you please expand on how$\frac {\ln (1+t)} t \to 1$ as $ t \to 0$. implies that there exists a constant such that $ln(1+t){\le}c|t| $ for $t{\le}1/2$

Comment: $\frac {\ln (1+t)} t $ becomes  continuous function on $[-\frac 1  2,\frac1 2]$ if you define its value at $0$ to be the limiting value  $1$. Any continuous function on $[-\frac 1  2,\frac1 2]$ is bounded. Take $c$ to  a  bound for $|\frac {\ln (1+t)} t |$.

Comment: Yes, it does extend to the complex case. @VivaanDaga

Comment: Is that because $ |ln(1+t)|upon|t|$ is continuous for complex t (if value at zero is one) and hence has a bound and since DOMINATED CONVERGENCE for sums works in complex case the above argument works ( though the infinite product must exist) where |t| for complex t is distance from(0,0)

Comment: For $|t|$ small $1+t$ does not take  values in $(-\infty, 0]$. So we can use the principal branch of logarithm in above argument. @VivaanDaga

Comment: Continuity of $|ln(t+1)|/|t|$ and the boundedness are not effected for the complex t is that correct?

Comment: They are true in the complex case also.

Comment: I can’t understand what closed set would work for the complex case in the real case we took [-1/2,1/2] what would be a good choice in complex case will all the points inside and on the circle of radius 1/2 be a good choice?

Comment: is there a thm that says that if the sum with terms $|a_{k}|$ will diverge than $\prod_{k=1}^{∞}(a_{kn}+1)$ will also diverge ?

Comment: can i apply this theorem blindly to any product and see if it allows me to switch limit and product . Or do i also need to show the product converges?